# Dict in dict, sort dictionary by nested key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested, key

I wanted to sort my dictionary in reverse order, order by nested dict key 0:

```
mydict = {
          'key1': {0: 3, 1: ["doc1.txt", "doc2.txt"], 2: ["text1", "text2"]},
          'key2': {0: 8, 1: ["doc6.txt", "doc7.txt"], 2: ["text3", "text4"]},
          'key3': {0: 1, 1: ["doc8.txt", "doc9.txt"], 2: ["text7", "text8"]},
}
```

to have this order:

```
'key3': {0: 1, 1: ['doc8.txt', 'doc9.txt'], 2: ['text7', 'text8']}
'key1': {0: 3, 1: ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt'], 2: ['text1', 'text2']}
'key2': {0: 8, 1: ['doc6.txt', 'doc7.txt'], 2: ['text3', 'text4']}
```

I've tried:

```
import operator

sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

But no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) creates a new sorted list – in your case a list of tuples representing the dictionary items. Dicts are still unordered in Python. [The new order preserving representation in 3.6 and newer](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict) is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon. If you need an ordered dict, use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: This isn't clear does the OP want to sort the items in his dictionary, or does he want to sort the items in is dictionary *and keep them in a dictionary structure*. If the former then @IljaEverilä's advice is the most pertinent, if the latter, then my answer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but I'd suggest using a `lambda` function, which pulls the relevant value out of the dictionary in index one for each item;

```
sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])
```

Printing the output into a format where we can easily observe the order outputs;

```
for item in sorted_dict:
    print(item)
```

Which outputs;

```
('key3', {0: 1, 1: ['doc8.txt', 'doc9.txt'], 2: ['text7', 'text8']})
('key1', {0: 3, 1: ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt'], 2: ['text1', 'text2']})
('key2', {0: 8, 1: ['doc6.txt', 'doc7.txt'], 2: ['text3', 'text4']})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this sorted method kept the order of the dictionary and  the dict type. It was perfectly working with my Jinja2 templates cycling through the results. Cheers!

Comment: @JozsefTuri No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

you should use:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

It will sort the dictionary to your satisfaction!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered in Python, and unless you use `collections.OrderedDict`, you will have to convert your structure to tuples and apply the `sorted` function

```
my_dict = mydict.items()

final = sorted([(a, b.items()) for a, b in my_dict], key=lambda x:x[1][0][1])
```

Output:

```
[('key3', [(0, 1), (1, ['doc8.txt', 'doc9.txt']), (2, ['text7', 'text8'])]), 
 ('key1', [(0, 3), (1, ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt']), (2, ['text1', 'text2'])]), 
 ('key2', [(0, 8), (1, ['doc6.txt', 'doc7.txt']), (2, ['text3', 'text4'])])]
```